# How to add a PNG image as background in Android with no alteration (banding)?

Tags: android, image, png

I'm trying to add a background that includes a gradient (I do want to use an image, not an android xml declared gradient effect).

This image is remarkably ruined by Android, it add some crappy banding whatever I try the result is the same (two capture of approximately the same region the distorted/normal images) :

[image: distorted] [image: normal]

My image is used as a layout background inside my layout XML :

```
android:background="@drawable/background_gradient_dithered"
```

I've tried to used an intermediate drawable to force dither whose xml is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/background_gradient" android:dither="true" android:antialias="true" android:filter="true"/>
```

I've tried to have the following code in my onCreate() :

```
getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
```

Both tries changed nothing.

Thanks

Comment: By banding, do you mean larger "steps" within the gradient? This could be a product of the bit depth of the emulator/device/png.

Comment: I don't think so : same problem occures on emulator the emulator on my two screens and two devices (Samsung Galaxy Ace & HTC Magic).

Comment: Would it be acceptable to create a 9-patch out of your bitmap file with only the bottom-most pixel being stretchable?

Comment: No, this wouldn't fit my need. Do you have any guess about the source of the problem ?

Comment: No, it's not. Just a stupid background (I've self-solved this, I've to take five minutes to make a descent answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct solution was .... I bet you've guess it : **restarting Eclipse.** I've learned it, every problem on Android might be a "restart Eclipse problem".

After some test I can add that enabling dethering is not useful when Format is set to PixelFormat.RGBA_8888

Readers should give a look to the answer given by @TenFour04, this approach can avoid to make drawable just to enable dithering.

```
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DITHER);
```

**EDIT :**

I've found out that even with these tricks the problem can persist. You can try to modifiy your PNG to have an alpha layer in it (change a pixel to a transparency of 99% for example), this would force android compiler to not play with it.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this in onCreate(). Older versions of Android default to no dithering.

```
Window window = getWindow();
window.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DITHER);
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out, just change the size of the `.png` files. I put them in the `mdpi` and resized it with Irfanview <-open source image editor to `1024x7xx` <- dont remember, [this comes too handy](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) 
and I set it for `300 dpi`. So they download it on a tablet and stuff, hope this helps :)