# Screen backgroud image looks different from iPhone Screen in android less then 2.3?

Tags: android, android-layout

Screen layout: parent main background image and another image as table image is child. table image as 3 row and semi transparent image.

When i used same both image in iphone then looks perfectly. See the screenshots.

[image]

But when i used same both image in Android less than 2.2 then transparent image of table and background image looks different...Please check this link...

http://screencast.com/t/T61v8Wf0MQ

here my layout screen code...

```
 <RelativeLayout  android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/main" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/table" >
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I used also imageview or another layout but same effect no improvement in color look.

My issue is look diffrent color on both screen android and iphone even i used same image.

Can anyone suggest me which parameter set so looks same color as iphone screen ?

Comment: maybe android:gravity="center", or "center_vertical" in relativeLayout1

Comment: Sceen on iphone and on android phones has different color profiles, so same image looks different, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after more researched finaly i found solution..

[How to add a PNG image as background in Android with no alteration (banding)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7741547/how-to-add-a-png-image-as-background-in-android-with-no-alteration-banding)

its work better to earlier.....